# Invalid month error shown in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a problem in SQL 
when i run below query it shows error like **ORA-01843: not a valid month**

```
> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')   INTO
> L_START_TIME   FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Why not just `select systimestamp into l_start_time from dual`

Comment: Or even better `l_start_time := systimestamp;`

Comment: Or if you wanted a string in the output - use `to_char` instead

Comment: Thanks frd but in this same query successfully run in my another system. May i change any system Time anything?

Comment: Calling `to_timestamp` on a `date` makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

**Never**, ever call `to_timestamp()` or `to_date()` on values that *are* already a timestamp or date. If you need a timestamp *value* use `systimestamp` for a timestamp value without time zone or `current_timestamp` for a value with time zone:

```
SELECT systimestamp 
  INTO l_start_time
FROM dual;
```

This assumes that `l_start_time` is defined as `timestamp`